# Exception about greendao3 encryption

Tags: android, encryption, greendao3

I am using greendao ORM. I am trying to encrypt my database using SQLCipher. Greendao automativally supports sqlcipher. So I wrote the following code for encryption.

```
DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new 
MyDevOpenHelper(HuoYunApplication.getHuoYunApplicationContext(), 
DBManager.DB_NAME, null);
Database db = helper.getEncryptedWritableDb(getEncryptedIMEI());
DaoSession daoSession = new DaoMaster(db).newSession();
return daoSession;
```

My app gradle dependencies are:-

```
 compile rootProject.ext.dependencies["greendao"]
 compile 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.4'
```

However whenever I perform any database operation using this session,it gives an error which caused an crash when my app starts,Even it is not a crash about encryption or greendao itself,but about a third party "so" dependency：

> 04-19 10:49:08.524 26995-26995/com.wuba.huoyun E/CrashReport: # CRASH STACK: 
>       04-19 10:49:08.524 26995-26995/com.wuba.huoyun E/CrashReport: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.baidu.platform.comjni.map.commonmemcache.JNICommonMemCache.Create() (tried Java_com_baidu_platform_comjni_map_commonmemcache_JNICommonMemCache_Create and Java_com_baidu_platform_comjni_map_commonmemcache_JNICommonMemCache_Create__)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.platform.comjni.map.commonmemcache.JNICommonMemCache.Create(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.platform.comjni.map.commonmemcache.a.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.platform.comapi.util.f.b(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.platform.comapi.a.c(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.platform.comapi.c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.mapapi.SDKInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
>                                                                         at com.baidu.mapapi.SDKInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)

I have checked greendaodemo in their official website,and I believe that I have add sqlcipher dependence in right way.So is there any genus that can help us solve this problem?

Comment: This crash has nothing to do with greendao.  You forgot an initialization step for some library from Baidu.  Not knowing the library, I don't know if it was a loadLibrary call you need to make for the native C library, or if its a java initialization function somewhere.  Either that or you forgot to build/package the C library for that architecture.

Comment: But before I added the sqlcipher dependence there is no problem in running my app.Ony when I added the dependency crash begun and the crash report showed that error.So I don't know how to do now.

Comment: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long com.baidu.platform.comjni.map.commonmemcache.JNICommonMemCache.Create()"  That crash is not going to be cause by greendao in any way.

Comment: I agree with you.Well I'll check other reasons.Thank you anyway.

Comment: Improved Code formatting and positions

Comment: Oh Thank you so much!!!